# Require function is marked as error in Brackets ide

Tags: node.js, adobe-brackets

The native function require of NodeJS is marked as error in Brackets IDE. I don't know what I have to do to change that. Thanks.

[image: Error]

Comment: Discussion of that issue from 2013 here: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/4021 and this suggestion to reconfigure Brackets to use jsHint: http://the-sourceterous.ghost.io/brackets-editor-disable-jslint-and-use-jshint-instead-2/.

Comment: More info here: http://exponential.io/blog/how-to-lint-javascript-using-brackets-on-windows/ on using brackets with jsHint instead.